# MS Excel Auto-Fill Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot

I am trying to build some analysis on MS Excel and I needed some help trying to pull a formula horizontally and vertically. I have the following datasheet in excel **Sheet1** -
[Product Sales Across Regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry8ps.png)

Now, I need to build a sheet that calculates the count of each product with each customer (**Sheet2** - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SexG.png)). There are approximately 100 Products (Columns) and 5000 Customers (Rows). I am using the formula `=COUNTIF($B2,Sheet1!$B$1)` for the field `Sheet2!C2`.

*Question:*
How do I drag the formula horizontally so that it will check for *Product 2, Product 3 ..... Product n*, while also be able to drag the forumla vertically to increment the first argument in `=COUNTIF($B2,Sheet1!B1)` to `B3`, `B4`... `Bn`. I want the formula to NOT increment the second argument when I drag it Vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write 
`=countif($b$2, Sheet1!B1)`

But if you need too many countif(s), use Pivot Tables instead.